# How to make icon spin in react-native-paper?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, expo, react-native-paper

I am having this `react-native-paper` button:

```
      <Button
        disabled={loading}
        icon="refresh"
        mode="contained"
        onPress={this.refreshData.bind(this)}
      >
        Refresh
      </Button>
```

How can I make the icon spin when `loading=true`?

Comment: Can you be more specific as in how do you want to "spin" the icon ?

Answer (score 5):

for the spinning icon do this.

declare one variable `refreshing` any boolean value when data refresh value set to be true and icon spinning start.

```
      <Button
        loading={loading}
        disabled={loading}
        icon="refresh"
        mode="contained"
        onPress={this.refreshData.bind(this)}
      >
        Refresh
      </Button>
```

react-native-paper button have props like.. loading
it's simply spinning icon

here [snack link](https://snack.expo.io/SkQHmLKXU)

Comment: Using `loading` prop I am not able to use the refresh icon. Using the refresh icon I am not able to sping. This example is exactly what I have posted, except you use two variables instead of one.

Comment: can you just check update code you control both disabled and loading by only one variable and please check working example visit  snack link

Comment: yes it work. the issue is just to use a different icon than the default spinner and to make the new icon rotate. For instance, how can I make the icon named `refresh`  rotate ?

Comment: At first, I downvoted but after reading the comments I upvoted. this works. thanks @rajantank